# Python will not parse this valid escaped JSON

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, parsing

Folks, this is exactly what the server sends:

```
{
  "type": 1,
  "data": [
    {
      "notificationId": "3006649",
      "accountId": "8-102ba1ae858f3e89",
      "pathIds": "969E844AE95",
      "pathTypes": "[\"6\"]",
      "pathNames": "[\"Direct Calendar\"]",
      "conversationUid": "94hirwrTx",
      "appInstanceId": "6",
      "pathCreatedBy": "[\"e050-910a19a97fe6\"]",
      "actionBy": "f3dc-e78f-e050-910a19a97fe6",
      "action": "COMMENTED",
      "relationship": "DIRECTED",
      "forUser": "8cc9-e050-910a19a96718",
      "timestamp": "1433168593342",
      "description": "<span style='color:#111111; '><a href=\"co:\/v1\/w_88bac084a1ae858f3e89\/feed?q=from%3A%22r%40wakanoo.com%22#title=A%20Qa%20Qu&amp;filter_value=-950afb167d96\" class=\"text-editor-at-mention  03b4-e040-950afb167\">@A B<\/a> Please verify.<\/span>",
      "data": null,
      "isArchived": 0,
      "isRead": 0,
      "actionByUsers": {
        "e050-910a19a97fe6": {
          "profile_image_type": "1",
          "profile_image_version": "1",
          "name": "Yabba dabba"
        }
      },
      "resourceLink": null,
      "notifText": null,
      "version": 2,
      "_explicitType": "InProductVO"
    }
  ],
  "message": "success",
  "revisionNo": -1,
  "errorCode": -1,
  "errorDetails": null,
  "_explicitType": "Response"
}
```

running json.loads(data) keeps throwing an error and the suspect is the escaped double quotes and I can't tame it. Any idea how should I fix this?

Comment: What is the error? Can you show us your code?

Comment: No code, no help. There's nothing wrong with this json, so there's nothing we can do to help you.

Answer (score 2):

It's valid json.

Probably what you've done is paste it into a string with the wrong quotes.

If you paste it into a raw string like this:

```
s = r"""<paste>"""
json.load(s)
```

It works properly.  Note the `r` prefix on the string literal.

Comment: One good way to test it yes. For this case I would have use r'''<paste>''' instead of double quotes, to better see the json double quotes, but it's just visual ;-)

Answer (score 0):

ValueError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 132 (char 131)

Apparently it's the espaced double quote. How are you testing this?

You cannot just copy paste the string within ''. You need to escape backslash. Check your data variable by printing it to see if you backslash are still there.

For me it works correctly if the backslash are retained.